# jQuery waypoints - Can I use waypoints twice on same page? (Seems like other sets of waypoints trigger others)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-waypoints

I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong, but I have a number of sections, some with sub-sections.

```
  <section id="section-one" class="section-top"></section>
  <section id="section-two" class="section-top"></section>
  <section id="section-three" class="section-top">
    <article id="sub-section-one" class="section-sub"></article>
    <article id="sub-section-two" class="section-sub"></article>
    <article id="sub-section-three" class="section-sub"></article>
    <article id="sub-section-four" class="section-sub"></article>
  </section>
```

so I set up two waypoint calls to perform different tasks on the `section-top` vs. `section-sub`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.section-top').waypoint(function(e,d){
    // Do something
  });

  $('.section-sub').waypoint(function(e,d){
    // Do something else
  });
});
```

However, as I scroll through the `section-sub` waypoints, it still triggers the `section-top`, even worse, it seems to be triggering `section-top` with its own waypoint, so there's no way to tell it not to act on `section-sub` triggers.

If you look at [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ubeyih/2/), you can see that the `trigger-count` is called in the first set of waypoints, but it is constantly going up when scrolling through the sub-set of waypoints.

Is this how it is supposed to function, am I doing something wrong? (Am I not supposed to register waypoints twice?)

Answer (score 0):

OK. With help of the creator of jQuery waypoints, Caleb mentioned that the reason this is happening is due to jQuery bubbling of custom events.

The solution was to put `e.stopPropagation()` in the second waypoint initialization.

[Github issue 114](https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints/issues/114)